# Create a Search Form that only Searches with WooCommerce Sale Products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

I am trying to create a search form that will search within products that are on sale/promotion within WooCommerce.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" post_type="product" post__in="wc_get_product_ids_on_sale" />
    <input type="text" size="16" name="s" value="Search"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add search value in getting post query like this :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    's' => 'search value',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
        array( // Variable products type
            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);

query_posts( $args );
```